# Capture Blank Nodes DOM and assign value

Tags: php, html, xpath, scrape

Ok i'm a bit of a newbie to DOM but I've managed to cobble together a semi working solution until now.

Using xpath I was looking for key elements within a web page and was looping through each instance which was fine, until I reached a node that is empty.

so when building my array I have say 20 nodes of one element but only 14 of another because the img isn't there all the time.

so in effect I have an array that looks like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [item] => PV10923
        [img] => image1.jpg
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [item] => PV10924
        [img] => image2.jpg
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [item] => PV10925
        [img] => image3.jpg
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [item] => PV10926
        [img] => image4.jpg
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [item] => PV10927
        [img] => 
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [item] => PV10928
        [img] => 
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [item] => PV10929
        [img] => 
    )

)
```

when in reality it should look like this

```
    Array
   (
[0] => Array
    (
        [item] => PV10923
        [img] => image1.jpg
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [item] => PV10924
        [img] => image2.jpg
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [item] => PV10925
        [img] =>  
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [item] => PV10926
        [img] =>  
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [item] => PV10927
        [img] => 
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [item] => PV10928
        [img] => image3.jpg
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [item] => PV10929
        [img] => Image4.jpg
    )

  )
```

Now the webpage source code looks like this

```
<div id="item">
<h2>PV PV10924</h2>
<p>
<a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="image4.jpg">
</p>
</div>
<div id="item">
<h2>PV PV10925</h2>
<p>
&nbsp; (assign a value)
</p>
</div>
<div id="item">
<h2>PV PV10926</h2>
<p>
<a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="image5.jpg">
 </p>
 </div>
```

Ive been looking all over to see if there is a way to capture the parent then do an if statement to see if the child is present then do the xpath if not assign node value x

Being dyslexic reading isnot my forte but believe me I'm trying...

Can anyone please advise me on the best route/method to achieve this....

Comment: so you want to check whether inside `<div id="item">` has a children of anchor with img inside? and is that really the markup? it has same multiple ids which doesn't make sense

Comment: Yes in essence yes if the <div> has a child in effect then via an if statement preform the capture otherwise is will assign a default so that the array is built to match the webpage. I believe your snippet below will more than do the trick by looking at it off to test it. I've not seen the "evaluate" function before so I'm also going to do some reading on that also coffee needed to keep my brain focused.

Comment: yeah you can test it. evaluate just like the name itself just evaluates the xpath query. glad this helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check for the descendants of the particular element. For example:

```
$sample_markup = '<div id="item"><h2>PV PV10924</h2><p><a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="image4.jpg"></a></p></div><div id="item"><h2>PV PV10925</h2><p>&nbsp; (assign a value)</p></div><div id="item"><h2>PV PV10926</h2><p><a href="http://www.example.com"><img src="image5.jpg"></a> </p> </div>';
// using the sample markup above
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // handle errors
$dom->loadHTML($sample_markup);
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$data = array();
$elements = $xpath->query('//div[@id="item"]');
foreach($elements as $e) {
    $item = $xpath->evaluate('string(.//h2/text())', $e);
    // checking
    $check = $xpath->evaluate('count(.//*[descendant::a])', $e);
    if($check > 0) {
        $image = $xpath->evaluate('string(.//a/img/@src)', $e);
    } else {
        $image = 'test.jpg';
    }
    $data[] = array('item' => $item, 'image' => $image);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Mf7oq0)

Comment: Had to make a minor tweak as i'm using a class so I had to include the method of evaluate into the class so I'm running your foreach with my for function then adding your foreach array into my for and it matches up great.